# event listener function goes into a loop? please help

Tags: events, event-handling, titanium, appcelerator

i'm facing a small issue with the fireevent. in one js file i'm firing the event like this:      `Ti.App.fireEvent('foo', {name:col});`

in an other file i'm listening to the event.

```
tableimg.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        if(e.source.backgroundColor==''){CreateTableWindow(1,e.source.id);}
        else{
            changeTheDinerStatus();
            Ti.App.addEventListener('foo', function(data) 
                                    { 
                                    var ke=data.name;
                                    alert(e.source.id+'@@@'+ke);
                                    e.source.backgroundColor = ke; 
                                    });                                                 
                                    }
                                    });
```

so here is the problem,  wen ever i'm firing the event the function in the listener is repeating itself.....

like this

wen clicked for the first time it runs once..1@@@#FFF
wen the second table is clicked it goes
1@@@#AAA
2@@@#AAA
for the third time
1@@@#BBB
2@@@#BBB
3@@@#BBB

this goes on like this for all the time....

Answer (score 1):

I can't see your DOM structure in front of me, but I think, the main problem is, that you add an event listener on every click.
You should not do this.
If you need to solve the problem this way, you should remove the existing listener

```
element.removeEventListener('foo',spyOnUser,false)
```